# GAE Python example for Direct Provider Federated Identities

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-openid

I am using GAE Python with Django. I tried the following in my code:

Relevant Python code:

```
providers = { 
    'Google'   : 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud', 
    'Yahoo'    : 'yahoo.com',  
} 

class BaseRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler): 
    def generate(self, template_name, template_values={}): 
       directory = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
       path = os.path.join(directory, 'templates', template_name) 
       self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values, debug=_DEBUG)) 

class MainHandler(BaseRequestHandler): 
    def get(self): 
        user = users.get_current_user() 
        log_in_out_url = users.create_login_url(federated_identity="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id") 
        if user: 
            log_in_out_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) 
        template_values = { 
                          'user': user, 
                          'log_in_out_url': log_in_out_url, 
                          "openid_url_google": providers["Google"], 
                          "openid_url_yahoo": providers["Yahoo"], 
                        } 
        self.generate('homepage.html', template_values);
```

Relevant HTML code:

```
<div id="login_username" > 
    {% if user %} 
        <span class="loginout"> <a href="{{log_in_out_url}}"> Log Out </a> </span> 
    {% else %} 
        <span class="loginout"> <a href="{{log_in_out_url}}"> Log In </a> </span> 
    {% endif %} 

    <ul class="dropdown" id="openid_login_providers" > 
        <li> <a href="{{ openid_url_google }}" > Google </a> </li> 
        <li> <a href="{{ openid_url_yahoo }}" > Yahoo </a> </li> 
    </ul> 
</div >
```

On "Inspect Element" in Chrome(when run on my Development server), i see the following substitution by Django:

```
<div id="login_username"> 
    <span class="loginout"> <a href="/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/"> Log In </a> </span> 
    <ul class="dropdown" id="openid_login_providers"> 
        <li> <a href="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"> Google </a> </li> 
        <li> <a href="yahoo.com"> Yahoo </a> </li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

[based on the python example provided on https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid?csw=1 ]

When the Google link is clicked, a file named "id" gets downloaded which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xrds:XRDS xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds" xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
        <XRD>
            <Service priority="0">
                <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
                <Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
                <Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
                <Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
                <Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
                <URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud</URI>
            </Service>
        </XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```

When the Yahoo link is clicked, it attempts to open the following link:

```
http://localhost:8080/yahoo.com
```

I am sure I am missing something obvious but not able to figure that out. What am i doing wrong

I am interested to provide login support only to Direct Provider Federated Identities (like google and yahoo) where username would not be required to be passed

Changes as per Lipis suggestion:

```
class Federated(BaseRequestHandler): 
    def get(self): 
        provider_uri = self.request.get('provider') 
        log_in_out_url = "" 
        user = users.get_current_user() 
        if user: 
            log_in_out_url = users.create_logout_url(federated_identity=provider_uri) 
        else: 
            log_in_out_url = users.create_login_url(federated_identity=provider_uri) 
        self.redirect(log_in_out_url) 
        return 

<ul class="dropdown" id="openid_login_providers" > 
    <li> <a href="/federated?provider={{ openid_url_google }}" > Google </a> </li> 
    <li> <a href="/federated?provider={{ openid_url_yahoo }}" > Yahoo </a> </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `providers` strings that you have are not URLs that you can simply redirect users to but as mentioned in the [official examples](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid#ex) they are URIs that should be used in the `federated_identity` parameter of the `create_login_url`.

There reason that it points you to `http://localhost:8080/yahoo.com` is because you are missing the protocol in the `<a href="yaho..."`, so what you have to do is to maybe link to something like this:

```
<a href="/federated?provider=yahoo.com">
```

Where you will handle the `&provider` argument and pass it to the `create_login_url(federated_identity=provider)` and continue from there.

---

Also instead of adding manually the providers you could provide all the providers to your template and render it like this:

```
{% for provider in providers %}
   <li><a href="/federated?provider={{providers[provider]}}">{{provider}}</a></li> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lipis.. I have added the changes you suggested at the end of my question above.. Could you please take a look and confirm if that was what you suggested.. or any correction or improvement..

Comment: also, in the above solution suggested by you, how do i make sure that the user returns to the same page(where he clicked the federated log in link) after logging in.. and not to my homepage (/)..

Comment: Yes that's a really good start I think.. I also updated the answer to reflect the changes